# Is the $A Z$ propagator transverse?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, standard-model, feynman-diagrams, correlation-functions, propagator

I know that the photon propagator is transverse to all orders in perturbation theory as it must be due to the Ward identities. But is the $A Z$ propagator (where $A$ stands for the photon), presented in the diagram below, also transverse to all orders? And if so, why?

[image: AZ propagator]

Comment: Is the $Z$ propagator transverse?

Comment: I don't think so

Comment: Aren't propagators gauge-dependent?

Comment: They are but the photon propagator is transverse independently of the gauge. I would like to know if the photon Z propagator is also transverse in every gauge.